# Are knitr subcaptions only for Latex?

Tags: markdown, knitr

I am using RStudio/knitr/markdown/pandoc/docx in Windows 7. I am having trouble getting captions on my plots when I print two of them side by side.
In the following example, I get no caption in my docx for the middle graphic. The figure number is correct in the last plot though.

Btw, I don't get the caption when I don't include the fig.subcap option either.
Thank you!

````
Title
========================================================


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(comment=NA)

fig.caption.num = local({
  i = 0
  function(x) {
    i <<- i + 1
    paste('Fig. ', i, ': ', x, sep = '')
  }
})
```

Some text:  

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6, fig.cap=fig.caption.num('My first plot')}
plot(cars)
```


Two plots:  

```{r fig.width=3, fig.height=7, fig.cap=fig.caption.num('Two plots'), fig.show='hold', fig.subcap=c('one plot', 'the other one')}
plot(cars)
plot(1:10)
```


Some more text:  

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=7, fig.cap=fig.caption.num('My last plot')}
plot(cars)
```


Finish text
````

sessionInfo()
    R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

```
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Argentina.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Argentina.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Argentina.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Argentina.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3   evaluate_0.4.3 formatR_0.7    knitr_1.2      stringr_0.6.2 
[6] tools_2.15.3
```

Comment: yes, it is a LaTeX-only feature

Comment: Thank you Yihui! I consider the question answered, would you like to post it as such? If you prefer I'll just mark it as answered myself in a couple of days and refer to your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just to mark the question as answered. Please see Yihui's comment above that confirms this is a LaTeX-only feature.